# Microsoft SQL Server does not start

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, startup

I have problem with start SQL Server 2008. I needed copy database from one computer to seced. I copy only catalog `DATA` from my actually working server and past this catalog to my new fresh installed SQL Server 2008. After this when I started SQL Server it does not start.

My error log is:

```
2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (X64) 
    Jul  9 2008 14:17:44 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      (c) 2005 Microsoft Corporation.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      All rights reserved.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      Server process ID is 6684.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Hewlett-Packard', System Model: 'HP ENVY Sleekbook 4 PC'.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 4124 at 2014-01-02 10:53:57 (local) 2014-01-02 09:53:57 (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.02 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2014-01-02 11:54:18.03 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.03 Server      Detected 4 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2014-01-02 11:54:18.06 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.23 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.26 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.43 spid7s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 0, file system access share name = 'SQLEXPRESS'.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.44 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2014-01-02 11:54:23.46 spid7s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.48 spid7s      The resource database build version is 10.00.1600. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.57 spid7s      Error: 15466, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.57 spid7s      An error occurred during decryption.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.62 spid10s     Starting up database 'model'.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.62 spid7s      Server name is 'MACIEK\SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.62 spid7s      Informational: No full-text supported languages found.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.62 spid7s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.63 spid10s     Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.63 spid10s     FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki.).
2014-01-02 11:54:23.63 spid10s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.63 spid10s     Unable to open the physical file "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki.)".
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid7s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid7s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki.).
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid7s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid7s      Unable to open the physical file "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBData.mdf". Operating system error 3: "3(System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki.)".
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid10s     Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid10s     FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku.) occurred while creating or opening file 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid10s     File activation failure. The physical file name "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf" may be incorrect.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid10s     Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid10s     Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid10s     Could not create tempdb. You may not have enough disk space available. Free additional disk space by deleting other files on the tempdb drive and then restart SQL Server. Check for additional errors in the event log that may indicate why the tempdb files could not be initialized.
2014-01-02 11:54:23.65 spid10s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

Answer (score 5):

I presume that on the source machine these were on the `E` drive and you just copied them over lock stock and barrel to the `F` drive on the destination?

One other option now you are in this situation is add startup parameter [`-T3608`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx) to tell SQL Server not to start any database except `master`.

You can then use `ALTER DATABASE ... MODIFY FILE` to fix up the paths for `model` and `msdb` to the new location.

Comment: +1, nice addition. It still leaves you with a master database of another server. (that could be bad, or not important which is impossible to say with the limited information we have now.)

Comment: yup -T3608 is handy :)

Answer (score 2):

By copying the complete DATA directory, you most likely also copied the system databases, specifically your master database from your old server and overwritten the system databases of your second SQL Server.

When copying a USER database in general, the easiest method is to make a backup of that user db on the source server and restore that backup on the destination server.

there is no need to ever copy the master, model, msdb or tempdb files from one server to another just to migrate a user database.

To fix your server again:

- If you have VSS snapshot backups of your master mdf en ldf file, it might work to place these back on your second server.

OR

- Restoring the master database [Restore master database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190679.aspx)

OR

- Rebuild the system databases [Rebuild system databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx)

OR

- Reinstall the SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

The error message on the log explains what's wrong:

> Operating system error 3: "3(System nie może odnaleźć określonej
>   ścieżki.)".

The message is some European language. (I'd hazard a guess for Polish, Czech or Slovak.) The English part, `Operating system error 3` provides more helpful an explanation:

> C:>net helpmsg 3
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

So Sql Server claims that it can't find neither data nor log files. Check that your system database files really are in directory

> E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

Use Sql Server's Configuration Manager to check for any typos on the path too. Mind especially extra spaces in the path, which are easy to miss.